# How to I kick of tests written in Geb and Spock using SpockConfig.groovy file

Tags: ui-automation, spock, geb

How to I kick of tests written in Geb and Spock using SpockConfig.groovy file , currently we have test in mutiple classes and each class is kicked of to run the test , but I want to run all the tests in different classes using a single kick off I know I can do that with SpockConfig but not sure how to implement it , can someone please help , thank you

Comment: What do you mean with kick-off tests? Could you please rephrase your question. How do you run your tests? What build tool are you using, which version of Spock&Geb ?

Comment: Kick off I meant Running tests. Currently I am running individual tests in a class , then go to the second class run the test right click and run test in intelli j ide.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, you can select your whole test folder or packages or a custom selection of classes in order to run your tests. If you use a build tool like Maven or Gradle, your build will run all your tests automatically. `SpockConfig.groovy` is not the right place to do that. Plus, the Maven or Gradle build will be imported automatically into IDEA or any other IDE you or your colleagues might use.